# Is there a way to cache the response received from a HTTP adapter?

Tags: performance, caching, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Is there a way to cache the response received from a http adapter in IBM MobileFirst Platform?

It would be more efficient to get data from cache for frequently used services instead of hitting the service again and again. Even an adapter(server) side caching would reduce response times considerably.

Is there a way to achieve this in IBM MobileFirst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism to cache an adapter response.

Maybe this will give you a way to do it: use Java in order to "manage" the caching. You'll need to implement the logic to:

1. Preserve the data in memory (in variables...)
2. Decide when to return the cached data
3. Decide when to purge the data and pass the request to the backend

If using JavaScript adapters, you can [invoke Java code](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/)
If using [Java adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/) (starting MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0), implement it there...

Perhaps you could also use a CDN, where you'll need to store data and decide in your logic when to reach to the CDN and when not to.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Idan's answer, there is no inbuilt way to do this. Some code approximately like this might help (put this in a Java class and use it from a JavaScript adapter) - this is *untested*:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MFPCache {
    HashMap<String, String> cacheStore = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private static MFPCache objectCache = new MFPCache();

    private static MFPCache getCache() {
        return objectCache;
    }

    public static Object getObject(String key) {
        String value = getCache().cacheStore.get(key);
        return value;
    }

    public static void setObject(String key, String value, long duration) {
        getCache().cacheStore.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Note that this answer doesn't handle:

- The case where an object isn't in the cache.
- Expiry of stale cache entries.
- Thread-safety in the Java world.

Will leave it for others to fix and edit those into the answer!

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you share more info on how you call this class from your JS Adapter?